# How to return a value from a function in react native

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-router

This function returns the token data from the API I am using.

```
// api.js
var token="";
    const tokenAl= {
  tokenner: function(){
    fetch("myurl/api/token", {
      method: "POST",
      headers: {
        Accept: "application/json",
        "Content-Type": "application/json-patch+json"
      },
      body: JSON.stringify({
        // here is not important
      })
    })
      .then(response => response.json())
      .then(responseJson => {
       token= responseJson.result.token;
        console.warn(token) // it's ok. I got the token.
      })
      .catch(error => console.warn(error));    
       // this.props.navigation.navigate("Customer"); // Customer sayfasına gidiş.
  },
}

export default tokenner;
```

Everything is okay. Now, how do I use this token value in the Login-Form.js file?

Comment: You need to use `state` inside the component, and call the state updater method of the component inside the `then` method callback where you are extracting the token.

Comment: I tried, but I could not. Can you write for me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all it's `export default tokenAl.tokenner`.

To use it in another file, simply add this at the top of your Login-Form.js

```
import tokenner from './api.js'; //assuming it's located in the same directory
```

You'll need to modify your tokenner function so that you can retrieve the token. Return a promise.

```
tokenner: function(){
    return fetch("myurl/api/token", {
      method: "POST",
      headers: {
        Accept: "application/json",
        "Content-Type": "application/json-patch+json"
      },
      body: JSON.stringify({
        // here is not important
      })
    })
      .then(response => response.json());
  }
```

Then in your LoginFormComponent

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import tokenner from "./api";

export default class LoginFormComponent extends Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = { token: null };
  }

  componentWillMount() {
    tokenner()
      .then(responseJson => {
        const token = responseJson.result.token;
        console.warn(token); // it's ok. I got the token.
        this.setState({ token });
      })
      .catch(error => console.warn(error));
  }
  render() {
    const { token } = this.state;
    return <div>{token}</div>;
  }
}
```

[Working example here](https://codesandbox.io/s/48wxyjwy27)

Comment: I appreciate you, my friend. Thank you. Problem solved.

Comment: I want to use the token I get on every page. I mean, it's enough to turn me on token once, I'll use it for various queries. How do I do that?

Comment: The easiest way is to use what we call a "store". Think of it as a service that you can easily use with every component. I recommend you check out mobx/mobx-react (https://mobx.js.org). However, if it's too much of a hastle to install (it can be depending on your setup), simply call your tokenner once and store the token as a cookie or put it in localstorage, then you can retrieve it from any component. (cookies: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/cookie, localstorage: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage).

Comment: What I do, if you're interested, is I use a store to retrieve my tokens and with that store, I save the key as a cookie. So when the page is refreshed, I always check to see if the key exists in a cookie, if it doesn't then I do an API request to fetch the cookie (which I'll then store in a cookie for the future).